# Watch for user idle time only on particular state

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, performance, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to build a system where we can elegantly check for user idle time(10 min). After doing some search ended up with [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r7zwq/25/).

Few cases which need to considered

1) whenever user change to drop down value to final, need to start a time tracker which monitors whether a user is idle or not.

2) if a user is idle for that time(10 min), need to do some background activity.

3) if a user changes to some other value apart from "final", then I have to unbind all events and timers attached to that controller.

4) if a user changes to some other state also, I have unbound all events and timers.

Sometimes, whenever I keep switching values, system physical memory is hiking up and eventually system hangs up ):( Am I running into some deadlock in stopping timer?

I know we can use `ngIdle` to do it. But we are already using ngIdle in whole application level to track user idle time and log a user out. so it is not possible to integrate it into a specific module controller, since its a singleton.

Any swift elegant solution? Kindly provide your thoughts.

Thanks in advance.